# file read error: success

Tags: c, unix

I have basic code as follows,

```
   fd = open("test.file", O_RDONLY);
   if (read(fd, &tempch, 1) < 1) {
         perror("File Read Error");
         exit(1);
   }
   printf("We could read from the file\n");
```

the test.file is present in file system and has been granted with 777 rights. the program throws error "file read error: success"... could anybody tell the possible reason? thanks

Comment: I've tagged your question generically as 'unix', if you are indeed using Linux, please feel free to re-tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for `read()` to return a zero count, it simply means that it has encountered the end of a file. If it returns a value less than zero, it is an error.

If -1 is returned, `errno` should be set, which will tell you what went wrong.

Does your file contain anything? Since you mentioned UNIX like permissions, the [POSIX specification for read()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) should be useful for you.

Comment: It is possible that `read()` return -1, without a error, maybe because a signal interrupt the read() call.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the return value of open and also how many bytes are present in test.file! If the file is of 0 bytes then return value of less than 1 is as expected.

From the read manual page

> On success, the number of bytes read
>   is returned (zero indicates end of
>   file), and the file position is
>   advanced by this number. It is not an
>   error if this number is smaller than
>   the number of bytes requested; this
>   may happen for example because fewer
>   bytes are actually available right now
>   (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading
>   from a pipe, or from a terminal), or
>   because read() was interrupted by a
>   signal.

Comment: @Tim Yes, this is what i wanted to convey - Return value from read is number of bytes successfully read which is further dependent on size of file  I have clarified the wordings

Comment: Ahh, clear now. I misread your answer initially. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but this

```
if (read(fd, &tempch, 1) < 1)
```

should almost certainly be

```
if (read(fd, &tempch, 1) < 0)
```